# Why scrapy image pipeline is not downloading images?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

I am trying to download all the images from the product gallery. I have tried the mentioned script but somehow I am not able to download the images. I could manage to download the main image which contains an id. The other images from the gallery do not contain any id and I failed to download them.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule


class BasicSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'basic'
    allowed_domains = ['www.leebmann24.de']
    start_urls = ['https://www.leebmann24.de/bmw.html']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths="//div[@class='category-products']/ul/li/h2/a"), callback='parse_item'),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths="//li[@class='next']/a"), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):

        yield {
            'URL': response.url,
            'Price': response.xpath("normalize-space(//span[@class='price']/text())").get(),
            'image_urls': response.xpath("//div[@class='item']/a/img/@src").getall()
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Raisul Islam, `'//*[@id="image-main"]/@src'` is generating the image url and I'm not getting any issues. Please, see the output whether that's your expacted or not.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule


class BasicSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'basic'
    allowed_domains = ['www.leebmann24.de']
    start_urls = ['https://www.leebmann24.de/bmw.html']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths="//div[@class='category-products']/ul/li/h2/a"), callback='parse_item'),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths="//li[@class='next']/a"), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):

        yield {
            'URL': response.url,
            'Price': response.xpath("normalize-space(//span[@class='price']/text())").get(),
            'image_urls': response.xpath('//*[@id="image-main"]/@src').get()
        }
```

**Output:**

```
{'URL': 'https://www.leebmann24.de/aruma-antirutschmatte-3er-f30-f31.html', 'Price': '57,29\xa0€', 'image_urls': 'https://www.leebmann24.de/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/363x/040ec09b1e35df139433887a97daa66f/a/r/aruma-antirutschmatte-94452302924-1.jpg'}
2022-09-07 02:35:56 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.leebmann24.de/bmw-erste-hilfe-set-klarsichtbeutel-51477158344.html> (referer: https://www.leebmann24.de/bmw.html?p=2)
2022-09-07 02:35:56 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.leebmann24.de/bmw-erste-hilfe-set-klarsichtbeutel-51477158344.html>
{'URL': 'https://www.leebmann24.de/bmw-erste-hilfe-set-klarsichtbeutel-51477158344.html', 'Price': '15,64\xa0€', 'image_urls': 'https://www.leebmann24.de/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/363x/040ec09b1e35df139433887a97daa66f/b/m/bmw-erste-hilfe-klarsichtbeutel-51477158433.jpg'}
2022-09-07 02:35:56 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://www.leebmann24.de/erste-hilfe-set.html> (failed 1 times): 503 Service Unavailable
2022-09-07 02:35:57 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.leebmann24.de/aruma-antirutschmatte-x5-f15.html> (referer: https://www.leebmann24.de/bmw.html)
2022-09-07 02:35:57 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.leebmann24.de/aruma-antirutschmatte-x5-f15.html>
{'URL': 'https://www.leebmann24.de/aruma-antirutschmatte-x5-f15.html', 'Price': '71,66\xa0€', 'image_urls': 'https://www.leebmann24.de/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/363x/040ec09b1e35df139433887a97daa66f/a/r/aruma-antirutschmatte-94452347734-1.jpg'}
```

Comment: sir, this expression is selecting all the photos outside of the main product image gallery. It is selecting 21 photos but the main product has only 4 photos. Also, this expression is throwing this error message "raise ValueError(f'Missing scheme in request url: {self._url}')"
ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: h

Comment: When I turn off  JavaScript, then a single image is static of the  main image gallery that's the output of the above code

Comment: you are correct. I also tried this expression before but what I am trying to say that I need other images from the gallery thumbnail too. The solution you shared it also worked for me but it is giving single image

Comment: Rest of images are dynamic and scrapy can't render JavaScript

Comment: I used Scrapy selenium and it worked

Answer (score 1):

This expression will get all product images except main (you said that you already have it):

```
'//div[@id="itemslider-zoom"]//a/@href'
```